# OpenCV "Hello World" example for Android

Tags: java, android, opencv

How to use OpenCV on Android? If possible, provide an example of a simple "Hello World" OpenCV code for Android.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Here](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/index.html) is an introduction to general OpenCV programming with some useful example programs, including a 'Hello World' .

The OpenCV wiki has a [page](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/Android) on the Android NDK, a tool to cross-compile OpenCV for the android platform.

[This](http://www.stanford.edu/~zxwang/android_opencv.html) quick tutorial on OpenCV with Android demonstrates how to use the NDK to cross-compile OpenCV for Android and put together a simple app.

That should get you started.

Kate.

Comment: I'd appreciate you marking the answer as accepted if its a sufficient answer to your question :)

Comment: .oh,sorry...Im new here ....how to mark it?...

Comment: links are broken :(